# Battery monitor always at 100%

Tags: linux-mint, kde, battery

I have Linux Mint 15 KDE and my battery monitor always shows full energy, even when it's about to be exhausted. Any ideas why is this happening?

acpi output:

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 0%, 02:27:21 remaining
```

Comment: What "battery monitor", where is it? Does it work correctly under a different operating system? Could you post the output of `acpi`?

Comment: It's in the kde toolbar. I also have installed linux mint Cinnamon and there it doesn't work neither.

Comment: Thanks, what laptop is this? Also try installing laptop tools `sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools`.

Comment: It's a lenovo ideapad Z500. I installed laptop-mode-tools and nothing has changed.

Comment: Same problem on Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon,